# receiving ajax call in JOOMLA?

Tags: php, json, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

i am tying two different statements to get POST result of ajax in JOOMLA

first JOOMLA native statement is not working fine. i also tried get() getVar(). . . not working. it returns null

```
  $vJson=$app->input->getCmd("chk");
```

but second one is OK and showing results

```
  $vJson = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

following is client side code

```
         xmlhttpp.open("POST","index.php?option=com_hello&controller=SetComObjects",true);
                xmlhttpp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                xmlhttpp.onreadystatechange=function()
                {
                if (xmlhttpp.readyState==4 && xmlhttpp.status==200)
                  {
                  alert("haha");
                  }
                }
                 xmlhttpp.send(chk);
```

my controller code

```
 public function execute()
 {

  $app=JFactory::getApplication();


  //following line return null in str_json
  $str_json=$app->input->getCmd("chk");

  //$model->_buildQuery();

  //but following statement is  giving OK result
  $str_json = file_get_contents('php://input');


  $str_json=json_decode($str_json);
```

Comment: Can you also add your controller code?

Comment: controller code added. . . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
          var data = "chk="+chk;
          jQuery.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index.php?option=com_hello&controller=SetComObjects?",
            data: data,
                    dataType: "json", 
            success: function(data) {


            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    alert( obj.name);//if its have a name
            }
         });
```

Your are not passing the `chk` to the controller as a parameter then how its gets there ?

Hope its helps..

Comment: ur method seems to work but all brackets are stripped down    "[{"XOID":"1","XPID":"1","..........  using file_get_contents('php://input');   ----------------and ----------------  "XOID1XPID1XobjectNameSin............ by your method

Comment: file_get_contents() is reading external url ? wht is the content your reading, bcoz the ajax statement never strip any json data if your return is in json format then don't need to decode it in php just do it in js

Comment: $vJson=  JRequest::getVar('chk');----------------- $vJson=$app->input->get("chk","null");------------------above are two native functions of joomla to access get and post variables. first one is ok but 2nd one was stripping slashes.  So i replaced it.  Thank you very much for you help. . .  problem resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I think that getCmd method is what causes the problem.
You can read about more `JInput::get()` [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput).

I'd suggest you to use:

```
$app->input->getArray($_POST);
```